# Rendering Firebase Data in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm looking to render some firebase data to the HomeFeed component. I update the state in the componentDidMount method. You can see what that looks like below. It's an array. Should I just map over that using the map function? How do I access the specific info like "title", "link", "type", etc. to be able to render it?

Thanks a lot!

```
var React = require('react');
var Rebase = require('re-base');
var base = Rebase.createClass("https://nimbus-8ea70.firebaseio.com/");

// TODO: Render Firebase data to screen.

// Home
// <Home />
var HomeContainer = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
        return (
            <div className="homeContainer">
                <HomeFeed />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

// Home Feed
// <HomeFeed />
var HomeFeed = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        base.fetch('article', {
            context: this,
            asArray: true,
            then(data){
                console.log(data);
                this.setState({
                    feed: data
                })
            }
        });
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            feed: []
        }
    }, 
    render : function() {
        return (
            <div className="homeFeed">
                {/* Use map function here? */}
            </div>
        );
    } 
});

module.exports = HomeContainer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`render` will run whenever `state` has been changed (unless you modify this behavior with, say, `shouldComponentUpdate`) so as long as you use `setState` properly your component will automatically update when its state changes.

If you're asking specifically how to turn an array into something that `render` understands, then yes, `map` is a very common way to do that. It might look something like this:

```
render : function() {
    return (
        <div className="homeFeed">
            {this.state.feed.map(function(ea){
                return <div>{ea.someProperty}</div>
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Note that you have to wrap `ea.someProperty` in curly braces because you're basically inserting JSX inside of a JavaScript expression *inside of even more JSX.* This kind of nested JSX/Expression/JSX structure is something you'll have to get comfortable with in React I'm afraid.

[More about `array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @staxwell If I've answered your original question please upvote and accept the answer. :)